Can I run Playwright Junit5 Gradle Tests on Sauce Lab Real Devices Chomre or Safari Browsers
I do have a Test Automation Framework. Playwright Java (Junit5 Gradle).
I am wondering if I can run my web tests on Saucelab real devices Chrome or Safari browsers.
I have used sauce_bindings but which allowing me only to run on windows/mac/linux(Desktop).
